# Summarising and grouping of sports data. Dplyr acrobatics required

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data from a sporting club, and wish to summarise player data over each season. The issue that I have is that the source database generates data for each grade that one player plays in over the season. I need to summarise numbers per season, combining the grades.

An example:

```
ID          Full.Season Group   Age Grade   Season type     Games   Total.Personal.Fouls    Total.Technical.Fouls       Total.two.points.made   Total.three.points.made
28139ABB    2008 Winter Girls   12  A       Normal Season   15      30                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2009 Summer Girls   14  B       Normal Season   13      28                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2009 Winter Girls   14  B       Normal Season   6       10                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2009 Winter Girls   14  AR      Normal Season   11      9                       0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2010 Summer Girls   14  AR      Normal Season   13      16                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2010 Winter Girls   16  BR      Normal Season   8       3                       0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2011 Winter Girls   16  AR      Normal Season   15      31                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2011 Summer Girls   16  BR      Normal Season   9       17                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2011 Summer Girls   16  B       Normal Season   5       13                      0                           0                       0                   
28139ABB    2011 Summer Girls   16  A       Normal Season   1       1                       0                           0                       0
```

but I want to summarise, so figure I need to produce something like this:

```
ID          Full.Season Group   Age Grade       Season type     Games   Total.Personal.Fouls    Total.Technical.Fouls       Total.two.points.made   Total.three.points.made 
28139ABB    2008 Winter Girls   12  A           Normal Season   15      30                      0                           0                       0                       
28139ABB    2009 Summer Girls   14  B           Normal Season   13      28                      0                           0                       0                       
28139ABB    2009 Winter Girls   14  B, AR       Normal Season   17      19                      0                           0                       0                       
28139ABB    2010 Summer Girls   14  AR          Normal Season   13      16                      0                           0                       0                       
28139ABB    2010 Winter Girls   16  BR, AR      Normal Season   23      34                      0                           0                       0                       
28139ABB    2011 Summer Girls   16  BR, B, A    Normal Season   15      31                      0                           0                       0
```

I can't get my head around how to do this. I think I need to group_by() "ID" and then "Full.Season", then collapse the "Grade" columns (concatenatating the characters in the Grade columns) and sum the rows with stats (Total.Personal.Fouls here, but other IDs have doubles in the other columns). But I don't know where to start.

Please help!

dput output:

```
structure(list(ID = c("28139ABB", "28139ABB", "28139ABB", "28139ABB", 
"28139ABB", "28139ABB", "28139ABB", "28139ABB", "28139ABB", "28139ABB"
), Full.Season = c("2008 Winter", "2009 Summer", "2009 Winter", 
"2009 Winter", "2010 Summer", "2010 Winter", "2011 Winter", "2011 Summer", 
"2011 Summer", "2011 Summer"), Group = c("Girls", "Girls", "Girls", 
"Girls", "Girls", "Girls", "Girls", "Girls", "Girls", "Girls"
), Age = c(12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16), Grade = c("A", 
"B", "B", "AR", "AR", "BR", "AR", "BR", "B", "A"), `Season type` = c("Normal Season", 
"Normal Season", "Normal Season", "Normal Season", "Normal Season", 
"Normal Season", "Normal Season", "Normal Season", "Normal Season", 
"Normal Season"), Games = c(15, 13, 6, 11, 13, 8, 15, 9, 5, 1
), Total.Personal.Fouls = c(30, 28, 10, 9, 16, 3, 31, 17, 13, 
1), Total.Technical.Fouls = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Total.two.points.made = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Total.three.points.made = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 |> 
  group_by(ID, Full.Season, Group, Age, `Season type`) |> 
  summarise(Grade = paste(Grade, collapse = ", "),
            across(Games:Total.three.points.made, sum))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 11
#> # Groups:   ID, Full.Season, Group, Age [7]
#>   ID      Full.Season Group   Age `Season type` Grade Games Total.Personal.Fouls
#>   <chr>   <chr>       <chr> <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <dbl>                <dbl>
#> 1 28139A… 2008 Winter Girls    12 Normal Season A        15                   30
#> 2 28139A… 2009 Summer Girls    14 Normal Season B        13                   28
#> 3 28139A… 2009 Winter Girls    14 Normal Season B, AR    17                   19
#> 4 28139A… 2010 Summer Girls    14 Normal Season AR       13                   16
#> 5 28139A… 2010 Winter Girls    16 Normal Season BR        8                    3
#> 6 28139A… 2011 Summer Girls    16 Normal Season BR, …    15                   31
#> 7 28139A… 2011 Winter Girls    16 Normal Season AR       15                   31
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: Total.Technical.Fouls <dbl>, Total.two.points.made <dbl>,
#> #   Total.three.points.made <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! question- why did you use |> and not %>% ?

Comment: `|>` is the "base pipe", that R supports since version 4.1. Unless you are using any of the advanced margrittr pipe `%>%` features it is recommended to use the base pipe. [See more here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/).